# center div and make it occupy 80% screen

Tags: html, css

i want to make my div center and occupy 80% of the screen , on max window size it is working fine but when resize window then my image div become very small;

```
<body style="background-image:url('img/Mesh2.png');background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size: cover; width=:'100%'">
    <h1>iSlider</h1>

    <div id="myImageFlow" class="imageflow">

        <div id="front">Initialy This is Front  </div>
        <!-- 
        <img src="img/img1.png"  id="id1" longdesc="img/img1.png" width="300" height="360" alt="img1" />
        <img src="img/img2.png"  id="id2" longdesc="img/img2.png" width="300" height="360" alt="img2" />
        <img src="img/img3.png"  id="id3" longdesc="img/img3.png" width="300" height="360" alt="img3" />
        <img src="img/img4.png"  id="id4" longdesc="img/img4.png" width="300" height="360" alt="img4" />
        <img src="img/img5.png"  id="id5" longdesc="img/img5.png" width="300" height="360" alt="img5" />
        <img src="img/img6.png"  id="id6" longdesc="img/img6.png" width="300" height="360" alt="img6" />
        <img src="img/img7.png"  id="id7" longdesc="img/img7.png" width="300" height="360" alt="img7" />
        <img src="img/img8.png"  id="id8" longdesc="img/img8.png" width="300" height="360" alt="img8" />
        <img src="img/img9.png"  id="id9" longdesc="img/img9.png" width="300" height="360" alt="img9" />
        <img src="img/img10.png" id="id10" longdesc="img/img10.png" width="300" height="360" alt="img10" />
        <img src="img/img11.png" id="id11" longdesc="img/img11.png" width="300" height="360" alt="img11" />
        <img src="img/img12.png" id="id12" longdesc="img/img12.png" width="300" height="360" alt="img12" />
        <img src="img/img13.png" id="id13" longdesc="img/img13.png" width="300" height="360" alt="img13" />
        <img src="img/img14.png" id="id14" longdesc="img/img14.png" width="300" height="360" alt="img14" />
        <img src="img/img15.png" id="id15" longdesc="img/img15.png" width="300" height="360" alt="img15" />
        <img src="img/img16.png" id="id16" longdesc="img/img16.png" width="300" height="360" alt="img16" /> 
    </div>
```

Comment: provide a fiddle of your code.

Answer (score 3):

Horrible code.

You shouldn't use inline style, and longdesc isn't supported.

Use CSS !

To center a div :

```
.class{
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
}
```

And if you need to use a custom attribute, use data-longdesc="" and not (NEVER) longdesc.
And if your 80% div become too small on resize, that's because it's a percentage.
Use min-width: 300px, per exemple.